# How to properly unset a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress to build my site and found the following issue: the parent theme has a script with the next jQuery function:

```
;(function($) {
  'use strict'

  var headerFixed = function() {
    if ( $( '.site-header' ).length ) {
      var headerFix = $('.site-header').offset().top;
      $(window).on('load scroll', function() {
        ...
      });
    } 
  };

  // Dom Ready
  $(function() {
    headerFixed();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This function is not working properly, so I'd like to substitute it for my own in my child theme, but I need to unset this one first. However, I'm not sure how to attempt this: I can't seem to access the function from outside the "$(function(){});" closure.

I also attempted to remove the function attached to the event handlers "scroll" and "load" of $(window) object, but I'm not sure how to go this way either.

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

P.D. Please notice  that I'm not looking for a enqueue/dequeue script solution since the parent theme script contains many other jQuery functions that I want to keep. I'm pursuing a jQuery/Javascript oriented solution to unset a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enduring thing that script does is this:

```
$(window).on('load scroll', function() {
  ...
});
```

You can't remove **just** that function because you'd need to have a reference to the function, and there's no (official) way to get that reference from jQuery. But you can remove **all** `load` and `scroll` handlers from `window` via the [`off` method](https://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$(window).off("load scroll");
```